# My Cloned WP site keeps redirecting to the old one

Tags: redirect, directory

This is my website: http://thiencheong.com.my/, I created my WP site at first at the ver2 directory, and when I'm ready for it to go live I cloned it over to the main directory.

But now whenever I'm accessing http://thiencheong.com.my/ the website automatically redirects to http://thiencheong.com.my/ver2/

I checked the database and for both home and siteurl both are http://thiencheong.com.my/

There's no redirect set up on my domain and the .htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help will be greately appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to clear your cookies and history? It's working fine here.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally forgot. I usually just check it on the incognito browser so that there's no history. I guess that's not the same afterall. Thanks so much! I feel so silly now haha.

Comment: I did the same steps as @evelyn and it's redirecting me to the /dev url where I originally installed it. Any other thoughts? I just did a clone into the main url directory like described above as well.